# How do I stop my ATI graphics chip from overheating?

Tags: fedora, graphics, ati, amd-graphics, optimus

My laptop comes with Intel HD Graphics 4000 & AMD Radeon HD 7670M; of which the ATI card is getting really hot.

System information:

```
[root@MISTRI ashesh] $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.1.6-200.fc22.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel02.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Aug 17 19:54:31 UTC 2015
```

I have tried [disabling the card](http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-12-04-turn-off-discrete-graphic-card-on-boot) and [setting power profiles](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#index3h2) but was unable to do both using the command line as root.

Disabling the card lead to no change and even a crash while switching profile gave me an invalid argument error.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/403981/247523

Try `echo battery | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_state`.